# While installing matplotlib i'm getting an error.What should i do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

While installing matplotlib i'm getting an error.What should i do?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
 sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jains\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t4qri_bp\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jains\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t4qri_bp\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jains\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5_2e7bsk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Install latest version of `setuptools` and give another try-- `pip install -U setuptools`. And try installing wheel `pip install -U wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `matploitlib` is supporting `Python 3.7`, but this one also worked for me in `Python 3.8`

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib==3.2.0rc1
```

Comment: Can You explain to me what this code means to say. Because I don't understand ==3.2.0rc1

Comment: It means release candidate, the version is not officially released. You install the ```matplotlib```version that is ```3.2.0.rc1``` Can you also mark my answer as being correct, please.